# How does WTForms know to use validate_<field name> if it is defined to validate a field?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

When I use WTForms to define a form, I can add a `validate_<field name>` method to the subclass, and WTForms knows to use it to validate the named field.  I find this interesting because the name of the method depends on the name of the field class attribute.  How does it figure this out?

```
class UploadForm(Form):
    image = FileField("image file")
    submit = SubmitField("Submit")

    def validate_image(self,field):
        if field.data.filename[-4:].lower() != ".jpg":
            raise ValidationError("nope not allowed")
```

Comment: Not sure if this is how Flask is doing it per se, but look at [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WTForms inspects the class when it is called (calling a class creates an instance: `form = Form()`) and records the fields and their names.  Then during validation, it looks if the instance has a method `validate_<field_name>`.

Within [`FormMeta.__call__`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.0.2/wtforms/form.py#L195-L199), it uses the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function to list the names defined on the class object and record the fields.

```
for name in dir(cls):  # look at the names on the class
    if not name.startswith('_'):  # ignore names with leading _
        unbound_field = getattr(cls, name)  # get the value
        if hasattr(unbound_field, '_formfield'):  # make sure it's a field
            fields.append((name, unbound_field))  # record it
```

Within [`Form.validate`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/2.0.2/wtforms/form.py#L305-L308) it uses the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) function to try to get the value of the name `validate_<field name>` for each field it recorded.

```
for name in self._fields:  # go through recorded field names
    # get method with name validate_<field name> or None
    inline = getattr(self.__class__, 'validate_%s' % name, None)
    if inline is not None:  # if there is such a method record it
        extra[name] = [inline]
```

Answer (score 1):

All members of all Python types are actually hashtables (`dict`s) and all type information is reified at runtime. So you can inspect any Python class from code.

As a quick interactive example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...   my_attribute = 'Something'
... 
>>> dir(Foo)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'my_attribute']
>>> Foo.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', 'my_attribute': 'Something', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>, '__doc__': None})
>>> [x for x in Foo.__dict__ if not x.startswith('__')]
['my_attribute']
>>>
```

Comment: have you tried flask-wtforms? is this how they do it?

Comment: @Zion: I don't know if this is how Flask actually does it. But the point is that all the type information is there at runtime. As I understand it, the question you asked isn't "how does Flask do this?" it's "how do web frameworks **like** Flask know names of user defined class attributes?" The answer, simply put, is because names of user defined class attributes are part of the class object itself.

Comment: my bad. my bad. yeah thank you for this.

this certainly has shed light on that mystery for me.